# Drawing two balls each time, number of drawings

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $5$ white and $3$ black balls in an urn.

We draw two balls at once, without returning them, until we draw a black ball.

How to compute the expected number of drawings?

Let $X(\omega)= $ number of drawings

$X=1$ if we draw at least black ball the first time.

The probability  $P(X=1) = \frac{ 3 \cdot 7 }{ {8}\choose{2} }$. Is that correct?

Two drawing are needed if we don't pick a black ball the first time and we do in the second draw.

$E$ - event: we drew two white balls in the first draw

$B$ - event: we drew at least one black ball in the second draw

So $P(X=2) = P(E)P(B | E)$

Could you tell me if my thinking is correct?

Comment: The probability that $X=1$ is not computed correctly. It is $1$ minus the probability of two white. So it is $1-\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}$. Or else we can say imagine the balls are drawn in order. Then there are $(8)(7)$ possibilities, and $2(3)(5)+(3)(2)$ favourables, probability $36/56$.

Comment: Three drawings may be needed; but you accepted an answer leading to nowhere. You don't know the correct figure, nor the way to find it.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Isn't $E(X) = P(X=1)+2P(X=2)+3P(X=3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X=1)$ gives the probability that in the first draw we obtain a white ball and a black ball, or two black balls. This is:
$$P(X=1)=\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}}+\frac{\binom{5}{0}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}.$$

Let $E_i$ be a random variables that tell you if the $1$st,$...$, $i$-th draw consisted of no black balls. $E_i=0$ if the $1$st,$...$, $i$-th draw has at least one black ball, and $E_i=1$ if the $1$st,$...$, $i$-th draw has only white balls.

Then $F(X)=1-P(E_x=1)$. And the cumulative distribution function $F(E_i)$ is not very difficult to compute.

For instance if $i=2$: $P(E_2=1)=\dfrac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{8}{4}}$.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that we draw two balls at a time. Will $P(E) = \binom{5}{2} / \binom{8}{2}$ and 
$P(B|E) = (\binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} )/  \binom{6}{2} $?

Comment: Could you tell me how to write down the formula for $P(X=3)$? I know I should use this events: $E_1$ - two white balls in the first draw, $E_2$ - two white in the second, and then in the third draw we must get a black ball. Will $P(X=3) = P(E_1)P(E_2 | E_1)$?

Comment: $P(X=3)=(1-P(E_3=1))-(1-P(E_2=1))$.

Comment: But $P(E_3=1)=0$, isn't it?

Comment: @Amith Yes. I'm checking the distribution to see if it is alright.

Comment: Well, $P(E_2=1)= 1/14$ and I get the same result if I do the calculations which I described in my second comment. By the way, is my first comment correct?

Comment: $P(E_1)=\binom{5}{2}/\binom{8}{2}$, yes.

Comment: @Amith $P(X=3)=F(3)-F(2)=P(E_2=1)-P(E_3=1)=1/14$ as you said.

Comment: $P(E_1)P(E_2|E_1)=P(E_2\cap E_1)=P(E_2)=1/14$.

Comment: Great, thank you, I think I understand the solution now!

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation for $P(X=1)$ basically assumes that the first ball drawn is black, then permits drawing any ball second.  You have not counted the cases you draw white first and black second.  The denominator should then be the ordered draws, so $8 \cdot 7$.  Your formula for $P(X=2)$ is correct.

Comment: I had left a comment saying it was fine, but I just realized this error. Good catch.